xyz cylindrical coordinates seem to have a skew z-axis drawing a helix
I want to draw a pentagonal helix using tikz 3D.
I wrote the following to do that:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach\x in {-6,...,6}{
    \draw (xyz cylindrical cs:radius=1,angle=72*\x-72,z=\x-1)--(xyz cylindrical cs:radius=1,angle=72*\x,z=\x);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}


It will iterate from -6 to 6 and each time it will move one unit along the z axis and rotate 72 degrees. We draw lines between successive points.
When I compile I get a helix. It looks skewed to the right but I figure that this is just the default location of the z-axis, not a big deal. However when I start drawing other parts of my figure I soon realize that this is not the location of the z-axis (for everything else at least).
To illustrate I will use a simple example where I draw in the coordinate grid:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
    \draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    \draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
    \draw[help lines] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
  \end{scope}
  \foreach\x in {-6,...,6}{
    \draw (xyz cylindrical cs:radius=1,angle=72*\x-72,z=\x-1)--(xyz cylindrical cs:radius=1,angle=72*\x,z=\x);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}


From the coordinate grids it would appear the z-axis is not aligned with the helix. So there must be something I am missing about my helix code that is causing a skew.
Why isn't my helix aligned with the axes?

It is drawn correctly, the z axis is the one which is coming out towards us.
